# Android SherlockListFragment list adapter with custom layout for each item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listfragment

I have a SherlockListFragment to display a list with certain information if is available on a fetched JSONObject. There are four types of information: phone, website, location and opening hours, and each one of those has its own "icon" to be displayed on the list. So, my problem is how to display custom layouts for each one of the types, and also how can I add and delete items from the list programmatically. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to handle it in the getView(int, View, ViewGroup) method of your ListAdapter. If you construct the adapter with a context and JSONObjects (in an array or JSONArray) it's pretty simple using each JSONObjects' has(String) method to check which it is. Just inflate a different layout depending on which the object has.

The getView(int, View, ViewGroup) method in your Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try { 
        jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (jsonObject.has("phone")) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_phone, null);
            TextView details = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_message);
            details.setText(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
        } else if (jsonObject.has("website")) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_website, null);
            TextView details = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_message);
            details.setText(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
        } else if (jsonObject.has("location")) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_location, null);
            TextView details = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_message);
            details.setText(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
        } else if (jsonObject.has("opening_hours")) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_opening_hours, null);
            TextView details = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_message);
            details.setText(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return convertView;
}
```

You will probably want to do more in each if statement, like add click listeners or whatever... unless you have autoLink on your views. If you're relying on autoLink to resolve the clickability of the data then you wouldn't need to inflate different layouts, you could just use switch the icon instead.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try { 
        jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_message)).setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL); //autoLink phone, address, etc.
        }

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_type_icon);
        if (jsonObject.has("phone")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.id.phone_icon);
        } else if (jsonObject.has("website")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.id.website_icon);
        } else if (jsonObject.has("location")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.id.location_icon);
        } else if (jsonObject.has("opening_hours")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.id.opening_hours_icon);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return convertView;
}
```

EDIT: Since it seems like you may need the separate views dynamically...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try { 
        jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); //This should have a linear layout with icons and textview for each node...
        }

        if (jsonObject.has("phone")) {
            LinearLayout phoneLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_layout); //This layout should already have the appropriate icon in it //*/
            phoneLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Necessary because the convert view doesn't guarantee what state this will be in as we've been modifiying them. //*/
            ((TextView) phoneLayout.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
        } else { ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_layout)).setVisibility(View.GONE); }

        if (jsonObject.has("website")) {
            LinearLayout websiteLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.website_layout);
            websiteLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) websiteLayout.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(jsonObject.getString("website"));
        } else { ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.website_layout)).setVisibility(View.GONE); }

        if (jsonObject.has("location")) {
            LinearLayout locationLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_layout);
            locationLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) locationLayout.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(jsonObject.getString("location"));
        } else { ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_layout)).setVisibility(View.GONE); }

        if (jsonObject.has("opening_hours")) {
            LinearLayout openingHoursLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opening_hours_layout);
            openingHoursLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) openingHoursLayout.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(jsonObject.getString("opening_hours"));
        } else { ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opening_hours_layout)).setVisibility(View.GONE); }

    } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return convertView;
}
```

list_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list_item_phone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/website_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list_item_website" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- ETC. A layout for each item. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nice answer, thanks, but what if I want to show more than one element on the list? How do I make the binding?

Comment: I see what you're doing now. This is something like a directory listing and each listing can potentially have more than one of those items. You'd want to have all of the options in your item layout and make each layout View.GONE if it doesn't exist. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: yeah! that's exactly what I want to do :D. So will that inflate all the layouts that I need in a list form?

Comment: thanks, I already created that xml layout file. But now, how do I bind it to the adapter itself? Something like: 

adapter = new MyAdapter(StartActivity.getAppContext(), android.R.layout.activity_list_item, data);

with data the JSONObject ?

Comment: You need to create your own class i.e.: MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter and call that in your code. Use the getView() method I put to override it's own.

Comment: The overhead of each if-else-elseif is big. He rather parse them asynchronously then supply to the adapter. That will cut down the overhead of parsing in getView() method. Cutting down to few if-else's will reflect on listview performance.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Yes, but for the OPs purposes it seems like they don't know which of the 4 types of data will and won't be available, but they've already done a bit of coding, I doubt that handling it in the adapter would cause too much of performance hit, it isn't as though a new layout is being inflated for each element...

Answer (score 1):

Create interface (or abstract class), lets say:

```
public interface DataType{

   public MyType getType(); //where MyType is my some enum.

}



public enum MyType { TYPE_1(R.layout.layout1), TYPE_2(R.layout.layout2), TYPE_3(R.layout.layout3)
private resourceId;
MyType(int resource){
resourceId = resource;
}
public getResourceLayout(){
  return resourceId;
}
 };
```

In your class implement this interface like:

```
public class MyData1 implement DataType{
    //...
    @Override
    public MyType getType(){
        return TYPE_1
     }

}

public class MyData2 implement DataType{
    //...
    @Override
    public MyType getType(){
        return TYPE_2
     }

}
```

etc...

Make your adapter take objects of type DataType.

In your `getView()` of your adapter decide which layout to inflate something like:

```
public View getView(..... ){
   //.....
   if(convertView==null){
      convetView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(dataAtThatPosition.getResourceLayout(), null);
      //.....
   }
   // use getType() to evaluate further actions if needed based on the type
}
```

Another approach is leaving interface/abstract class behind and decide which layout to inflate based on the assignation of the class. In that case your adapter will take generic type T, when deciding which layout to inflate you will have to do something like this in your getView():

```
public View getView(..... ){
      T data = getItemAtPosition(position);
      if(convertView==null){
         convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate((data.isAssignableFrom(MyData1.class)? R.layout.layout1 : data.isAssignableFrom(MyData2.class)? R.layout.layout1 : R.layout.layout3), null);
      }


}
```

Personally I think the second approach is quite dirty. :)

I hope this gives you idea. :)

Comment: nice one, I would not have thought it, but the enum MyType has the same layout for each element?

Comment: Nope, see the constructor of the enum, there is `int` argument which later will be used to specify different layout and get it where you needed.

Sorry, it is my copy-paste mistake, it should be different layout for each, I made mistake by putting same layout for all. :) (Edited)